# Child row in XPath Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I want to select the element in this XPath with Selenium in Python:

`//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/a/div/div[2]`

The path is:

```
#react-root > section > main > article > div:nth-child(4) > div > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > a > div > div._si7dy
```

And then I tried this string in Python:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//article/div/*[2]/div/div/*[1]/div/*[1]/a/div/div/*[2]').click()
```

And it doesn't work, I've also tried a lot of different ways to write it but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Update the question with the relevant _HTML_

Comment: Have you tried making a relative path using an element attribute? The long your path is, the more likely it is to be wrong. Maybe an element in this path has an id or a unique class?

Comment: Have you checked if that path is on an Iframe?

Comment: 'And it does'nt work' , what's going wrong? Is there an exception thrown?

Comment: `article > div:nth-child(4)` is not the same as `//article/div/*[2]`